# Variable in JavaScript giving the same value

Tags: javascript, arrays, arraylist

in this code I am trying to display cats from cats list when they get selected then increase the score of each one of them when they get selected
The problem here is the count variable is connected between all cats. So when I click on any photo the count variable it self gets increased. How can I assign different value of the variable count to each cat? I hope it is clear enough

```
// displaying the cat when clicked 
for (var i = 0; i < catsColumn.length; i++) {
(function () {
    var cattt = cats[i];
     catsColumn[i].addEventListener('click', function () {
    var catDisplay = document.createElement('div');
    var catScore = document.innerHTML = "<p id=" +  cattt + ">0</p><img class='catDisPic' src='"+ cattt +".jpg'>";
    catDisplay.innerHTML = catScore;
    catsDisplay.appendChild(catDisplay);
    // selecting the cats in the display area and adding event listener

        var catPicDis = catsDisplay.getElementsByClassName('catDisPic');
    for (var i = 0; i < catPicDis.length; i++) {
        (function () {
            var count = 0;
        catPicDis[i].addEventListener('click', function(){

            this.previousSibling.textContent = ++count;
        })

    }())
    } 
})
}())
```

}

Comment: *count* is global. What is *catsDisplay*? Presumably you've previously used *getElementById* or *querySelector* to assign a single DOM element?

Comment: Yes I selected the catsDisplay is where the cat divs are

Comment: When I declare count inside the function it doesn't increment

Comment: Declare it in the IIFE, not the listener. See my answer.

Comment: @Tushar, We don't need to..Inner function can access outer variable..We are not using `i` anywhere in the `handler`..Correct me if I am wrong..

Comment: @Rayon Dabre yes you are right. We don't need it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Within the IIFE, *count* is global, so:

```js
var catPicDis = document.getElementsByClassName('catDisPic');
for (var i = 0; i < catPicDis.length; i++) {
  (function() {
    // keep count in closure
    var count = 0;
    catPicDis[i].addEventListener('click', function() {
      this.previousSibling.textContent = ++count;
    })
  }());
}
```

```html
<div class="catDisPic">catDisPic</div>
<div class="catDisPic">catDisPic</div>
<div class="catDisPic">catDisPic</div>
```

Comment: Thanks Rob, this fixed the problem but another problem appeared which is: when I add new cat to the display the counter reset for all the cats :)
I will add the full code so you can see it in the main question